# How do I get my Android app to track your total distance traveled?

Tags: android

I'm writing a simple app that measures the total distance you've traveled after pressing a button. It essentially integrates your speed over time. This is the code I have for it.

```
 public void onClickDistance(View view){
    getLocation();
    float speed;
    float distance;
    distance = 0;

    if(myLocation != null){

        while(true)
        {

            try {
                Log.v("msg", "WAIT CheckFrequencyRun");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                accuracyEdit.setText("" + roundUp(myLocation.getAccuracy(), 2) + " meters");

                distance = distance + myLocation.getSpeed();
                distanceEdit.setText("" + roundUp(distance, 2) + " meters");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }
    else{
        Log.e("GPS1", "myLocation = null");
    }

}
```

However, nothing happens when I press the "track distance" button, but I think the app is caught up trying to calculate something it can't. I tried to increase the waiting time to 10 seconds, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: "Nothing Happens" - Because there is an infinite loop on your main thread

Comment: Another problem is that you are only calling getLocation() once, so every time you call myLocation.getSpeed() it will be the same result.

Comment: @Naveed I wanted it to continuously check the user's speed and update it. I'll add a way to break out of the loop once I get it working.

Comment: How are you fetching the location?  The my location object would provide the same location since it wont be updated.  You should request for location updates using [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Comment: all you need to do is create 3 Strings probably doubles. old (lat,lng), current (lat,lng) and total. when you start the record distance on your app you record old, after 5 seconds record current. do the calculation in meters and add to the total. set current  as the  old. repeat the process till you stop. divide the meters by 1000 if you want Km or 1609.34 fo Miles. to have a more accurate distance you could run the process every 2 seconds